# Search while typing

Tags: asp.net

I have a textbox and a listbox. The listbox is filled by a sqldatasource and I want to be able to filter out the listbox based on what's typed in the textbox.  The filtering/searching works but ONLY once the textbox loses focus.

What I need is the listbox to filter/search WHILE I am typing and not require the textbox to lost focus.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this yourself, i.e. no third party tools, you need to catch the `textchanged` event and update the source yourself based on what's typed. It's probably better if you use 3rd party tool or do this via javascript or at least ajax call to have better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have focus at the end of the character because abstractly speaking, there is no way to find out automatically when user will stop typing, so everything goes during typing.

Are trying to do this this with Jquery? or Ajax?

Comment: I don't really know what to use. I've not used either too much but I'm fairly good at picking up new things so if you can point me to something that'd be great.